# userauth_pubkey: unsupported public key algorithm: spki-sign-rsa

Tags: sshd

I'm trying to SSH into my Debian 12 box from my 1988 Mac SE/30.
I know that I need to enable old algorithms -- but it's still better than telnet.

What I've got so far in my `sshd_config` is:

```
KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa

Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
# 3des for MacSSH
# aes128-cbc for 10.2
MACs umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5

PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

however I still can't get the Mac to connect. The problem seems to be:

```
userauth_pubkey: unsupported public key algorithm: spki-sign-rsa [preauth]
```

But I can't find out what this means or what to do about it -- there seems to be no such algorith `spki-sign-rsa`.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do `ssh -v ...`. This first level of verbosity will cause each end to. log messages ssying "I support these encryption methods".

Comment: Not an option in MacSSH!

Answer (score 0):

Regenerated the key pair on the SE/30 and copied the public key to `.ssh/authoorized_keys` and now it works.
It seems that the log message in `/var/log/auth.log` was rather misleading.